# QWebView for Android target on Qt5.3 on windows pc, ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebkit, qtandroidextras

I am writing a code for android from Windows pc. I have Qt 5.3 and I added the following line to my .pro file for to use QWebView, as suggested:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

however, when I run qmake, I get the this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

Comment: The same question: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37586

Answer (score 2):

QtWebKit is not supported on Android as per this blog post:

[Qt on Android Episode 1](http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/)

As you can see in the ["New Features" for 5.3](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.3), the original plan posted by BogDan has not changed in that regard:

> Qt WebKit:

```
* Support for HTML5 Video Track. Subtitles and captions for HTML5 video.
* Support for Indexed DB API. See http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/
* Improved support for Mac HiDPI mode
```

I think your best bet is `QtWebEngine` for 5.4 the earliest. Digia and the Qt Community as a whole switched to that a while ago, which was "announced" during the Qt Contributors Summit last year in Barcelona by Lars. In my understanding, QtWebKit is more or less in maintenance mode, but at least not as heavy feature development as it used to be.

Comment: Sorry, it was Bilbao, not Barcelona, but the gist remains. ^^